# Windows: How to start a file copy job on a remote server without passing through the network?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, copy

I'd like to copy a large file on a remote computer, to the same remote computer, without going through the network.

The computer on which the files to be copied are is running Windows Server 2003.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: You'd like to copy a file from one directory on the computer to another? Is this a troll?

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear, I want to program that kind of action to be executed in batch mode from another computer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at PowerShell 2's remotin capabilities. It will run a complete script on a remote system (or the same script on many remote systems concurrently).

http://blogs.msdn.com/wmi/archive/2009/07/24/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use psexec to run the copy command on the remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: I need it in batch mode.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell remoting is your best option.  While PSexec and running a copy command remotely will work PSexec is often flagged by antivirus software as a virus.  See [PowerShell 2.0 remoting guide: Part 1 – The basics](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1025)

Comment: Powershell also gets flagged by good AV software when trying such things.

Comment: Really!? Can you say which one you've seen doing that?  I know why psexec gets flagged- many older viruses incorporated it into their code, but I hadn't heard of ws-man getting flagged

Comment: I can't recall which ones I've seen flag it but in each case heuristic detection was set to maximum, so it's to be expected. Any AV software that doesn't flag such remote control methods is questionable anyway.